# monacaとniftymbaasを使用して、iOS でプッシュ通知を実装したい。

Tags: ios, monaca

現在、monacaとniftymbaasを使用してプッシュ通知が使えるアプリを作成しています。
プログラムは作成済みなのですが、デバッグビルドをする際のiosビルド設定で困っております。
iOS dev centerでprovisioning file、証明書の取得をして秘密鍵とCSRのインポートまではうまくいったんですが、証明書のアップロードでこれはデペロッパーの証明書ではないですよと言うようなエラーが出てしまい先に進めません。何度も証明書を取得し試しているのですが同じエラーが出てしまいます。
monacaの設定の問題でしょうか？
それとも証明書の取得がうまくいってないんでしょうか？

どなたかわかる方ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wakuさん、こんにちは。
恐らく自分がはまったのと同じ個所かと思われますのでお助けになれば。。。

デバッグビルドをする際の、[iOSのビルド設定]でアップロードする証明書は、
Apple developerログイン
→Member Center
→Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
→Certificates
→Development
→iOS App Development
これです。

自分は、「プッシュ通知をするんだから…」と思い込み
Certificates
→Development
→Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)
このプッシュ通知のための証明書を何度も何度も作っては消し…で半月くらい費やしたでしょうか…

ちなみにプッシュ通知を実装したアプリには、全部で4つ証明書が必要になります。
●デバッグビルド用
・Certificates→Development→iOS App Development
　アプリの証明書。Monacaにアップロードする「デベロッパー証明書」はこれ。
　アップロードする「秘密鍵」もこの証明書から書き出したもの。
・Certificates→Development→Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)
　プッシュ通知のための証明書。プッシュを実装しなければ不要。
　NCMBにアップロードするp12ファイルはこの証明書から書き出したもの。
●リリースビルド用
・Certificates→Production→App Store and Ad Hoc
　Monacaにアップロードする「ディストリビューション証明書」はこれ。
　アップロードする「秘密鍵」もこの証明書から書き出したもの。
・Certificates→Production→Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)
　プッシュ通知のための証明書。プッシュを実装しなければ不要。
　NCMBにアップロードするp12ファイルはこの証明書から書き出したもの。

Comment: kihan さんのご指摘通りPUSH通知用の証明書をデベロッパーの証明書とまちがえておりました。
とても助かりました、ありがとうございました。