# monacaのpush機能実装時における、デベロッパー証明書登録エラー

Tags: ios, monaca, push-notification

Monacaで、iosの開発をしております。 
Nifty cloudと連携して、push通知を送ろうとしているのですが、iosビルドの設定の時点で、デベロッパー証明書が登録できずに困っています。 
ios dev centerにて、デベロッパー証明書を作るときに、 
Apple Push Notification service SSl (Sandbox) 
というのを選択してしまうと、証明書自体は発行できるのですが、Monacaのiosビルド設定画面で証明書をアップロードすると、写真のようなエラーがでてきてしまいます。 
どのようにすれば、エラーなく、証明書を登録することができるのでしょうか?? 
もしくは、他の方法で、Monacaとnifty clloudのmBaaSを連携することはできるでしょうか??
[image: monacaのiosビルド設定画面：デベロッパー証明書をとうろくした際のエラー]

Comment: つい先日、似た質問に回答しました。
[こちら](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23297/monaca%E3%81%A8niftymbaas%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-ios-%E3%81%A7%E3%83%97%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E9%80%9A%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます!!
→Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
→App IDs
→App ServicesのEnable Services
の項目は、チェックされましたでしょうか??

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/30900

Answer (score 1):

はい。プッシュの項目をチェックしました。最終的には下記の3項目にチェックが入った状態になります。
・Game Center　←　これと
・In-App Purchase　←　これはもともとチェックされている
・Push Notifications　←　これにチェックする

Comment: とても助かりました！
本当に、ありがとうございます！！！